# Qt - custom window chrome

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyside

I want to create an app with QT v 5.3 (PyQT/PySide) that has a custom window chrome (somewhat resembling windows modern ui/metro) - [here's](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spooky/faf-redesign/master/1-pane.png) the design.

Now my question is - should I go with standard QMainWindow, use the Qt.FramelessWindowHint and just add some widgets (for title bar, status bar, window action buttons) or should I create my own QWindow equivalent or maybe there's another option?

Comment: I had a project a while back where I tried to achieve this as I feel the native look is pretty boring for the app I was trying to create. I ended up using TideSDK instead of PyQT for what I was trying to achieve. You could override a lot in the QtGui.QWindow object but it will be very tough.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the needed design with frameless window and custom controls. I did similar things in the past with Qt Widgets and it was really painful.

For your suggested UI, I would go with [Qt Quick](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-index.html). It would be pretty easy and straight forward to do all of custom controls and with style standard (see [Qt Quick Controls](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-index.html)) ones to your needs.

In addition you would need to implement custom handling for moving the window with mouse, as your window would lack the default header.

Comment: Yeah, for fancy-schmancy UIs with lots of custom design and controls, possibly touch interaction, go for Qt Quick. It's very apt for these purposes, however note that you can just as well create native-looking apps with Qt Quick... especially with the better Qt Quick Controls integration of upcoming Qt 5.4 and 5.5!